# pandas combine pivot table with DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I want to group my data set and enrich it with a formatted representation of the aggregated information.

This is my data set:

```
h = ['A', 'B', 'C']
d = [["a", "x", 1], ["a", "y", 2], ["b", "y", 4]] 
rows = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=h)

   A  B  C
0  a  x  1
1  a  y  2
2  b  y  4
```

I create a pivot table to generate `0` for missing values:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(rows,index=["A"], values=["C"], columns=["B"],fill_value=0)

   C   
B  x  y
A      
a  1  2
b  0  4
```

I groupy by `A` to remove dimension `B`:

```
wanted = rows.groupby("A").sum()

   C
A   
a  3
b  4
```

I try to add a column with the string representation of the aggregate details:

```
wanted["D"] = pivot["C"].applymap(lambda vs: reduce(lambda a,b: str(a)+"+"+str(b), vs.values))
```

> AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'values'", u'occurred at index x')

It seems that I don't understand applymap.

What I want to achieve is:

```
   C  D
A   
a  3  1+2
b  4  0+4
```

Comment: `applymap` applies the function element-wise, hence `vs` is a scalar (an `int` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove `[]` from parameters in [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), so you remove `Multiindex` from columns:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(rows,index="A", values="C", columns="B",fill_value=0)
```

Then [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) values by columns:

```
pivot['C'] = pivot.sum(axis=1)
print (pivot)
B  x  y  C
A         
a  1  2  3
b  0  4  4
```

Cast by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) `int` columns `x` and `y` to `str` and output to `D`:

```
pivot['D'] = pivot['x'].astype(str) + '+' + pivot['y'].astype(str)
print (pivot)
B  x  y  C    D
A              
a  1  2  3  1+2
b  0  4  4  0+4
```

Last remove column name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`) and [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) unnecessary columns:

```
pivot = pivot.rename_axis(None, axis=1).drop(['x', 'y'], axis=1)
print (pivot)
   C    D
A        
a  3  1+2
b  4  0+4
```

But if want `Multiindex` in columns:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(rows,index=["A"], values=["C"], columns=["B"],fill_value=0)

pivot['E'] = pivot["C"].sum(1)
print (pivot)
   C     E
B  x  y   
A         
a  1  2  3
b  0  4  4

pivot["D"] = pivot[('C','x')].astype(str) + '+' + pivot[('C','y')].astype(str)
print (pivot)
   C     E    D
B  x  y        
A              
a  1  2  3  1+2
b  0  4  4  0+4

pivot = pivot.rename_axis((None,None), axis=1).drop('C', axis=1).rename(columns={'E':'C'})
pivot.columns = pivot.columns.droplevel(-1)
print (pivot)
   C    D
A        
a  3  1+2
b  4  0+4
```

EDIT:

Another solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(rows,index=["A"], values=["C"], columns=["B"],fill_value=0)

#remove top level of Multiindex in columns
pivot.columns = pivot.columns.droplevel(0)
print (pivot)
B  x  y
A      
a  1  2
b  0  4

wanted = rows.groupby("A").sum()
wanted['D'] = pivot['x'].astype(str) + '+' + pivot['y'].astype(str)
print (wanted)
   C    D
A        
a  3  1+2
b  4  0+4
```